# How to transform a byte buffer containing zeroes into a string

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have a byte array as input. This should be the binary representation of standard conforming UTF8 HTML. It is, but most of the time only. Sometimes it also contains embedded nulls (`\x0` character or `NUL`). This is not under my control. I need to transform this byte array into a string.

Tried so far:

- Obviously using a `StreamReader` or `TextReader` does not work as it stops on hitting the first `NUL`
- `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` does not work either - also stops on the first `NUL`

What worked but is rather unelegant:

```
   mynewarray = myoldarray.Where( x => x!=0).ToArray();
   var output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mynewarray);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this excepted in creating a new byte array skipping the `NUL` chars and then use one of the solutions above? The byte array can be pretty big, more than 2-4 Mb... The MSDN tells that Strings might actually contain embedded `NUL` but does not tell what are the best approaches to handle such strings.

Comment: Actually, `UTF8.GetString(byte[])` should not stop at a zero... But after that, you do have a string containing `'\0'`

Comment: I was relying on the length property for my assertion which was far less than the buffer size. I need to double check.

Comment: Length of the string will be less than buffer size if any extended characters are in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is already right. It will contain the `NUL` characters. But when you use a string with the included `NUL` chars you will get all kind of problems.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString` does not stop at \0 as you see in my example.

See what happens when I output such a string:

```
  var text = new byte[]{65, 65, 0, 65};
  var s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(text);
  Console.WriteLine("len is: " + s.Length + " chars");
  Console.WriteLine("text: '" + s + "'");      
  Console.WriteLine("this line doesn't appear because NUL was sent to console");
```

output is:

```
len is: 4 chars
text: 'AA
```

Comment: You are fully right, the code was indeed already working... I overlooked that the length was mismatching because of the `\r\n` conversion and I missed one digit. The length was actually bigger than the original array. I fell dumb now.. To feel a bit silly now. I could then use the `Replace` method to remove the `NUL` chars in the converted string. That makes the code safer IMHO, because in some encoding, a 0 byte might have been valid. Now I can avoid throwing away the 0 bytes in the source array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of GetString which takes a start index and the number of bytes to decode

```
var output = Encodeing.UTF8.GetString(mynewarray, 0, mynewarray.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, but you might be able to optimize it by manually controlling buffer sizes (not sure what `Where()` does) and/or by using unsafe code.

Pointer math is great for rapid iteration through arrays and you have complete control over how far you wish to advance your memory pointers (thus it being "unsafe"). This means you can consume/skip any character at will. I use optimized buffers + unsafe code regularly in c# for this purpose.

The .NET framework uses buffering and unsafe code where appropriate, but since you know your exact requirements you may be able to tweak performance. However, it will result in more verbose code.